# CSS Animation not working in IE11

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I've got an animation that works in chrome but not IE even though I have the syntax for both present.  What's happening hear is when you click a button, a hidden div becomes visible (display: block) and then slides in from off screen.

EDIT: The code below seems to work when I copy it into jsfiddle, but I can't get it to work on my site.  Here's the url of it live: http://www.fastfoodnutrition.org/test/

HTML

```
    <ul id="menulist">
            <li>
                <a  title=" Restaurants" href="/restaurants.php">Restaurants</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title=" Calculator" href="/calculator.php">Nutrition Calculator</a>
            </li>

    </ul>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menubutton").click(function(event){
        $("#menulist").css("display","block");
        $("#menulist").addClass("slidein");

    });
});
```

CSS

```
#menulist{
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 50px; 
  right: -160%;
  float:none;
  display:none;
}

.slidein{
    -webkit-animation: slidein .5s ease-in-out .2s 1 normal;    
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    animation: slidein 1s;  
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
    0% {right: -160%;}
    100% {right: 0;}

}
@keyframes slidein {
    0% {right: -160%;}
    100% {right: 0;}

}
```

Comment: Try moving the keyframes to the top of the stylesheet.

Comment: Gave it a shot, but no dice.

Comment: I always include units , not sure if leaving off the % from right: 0 would cause it?

Comment: In the ie key frames you have right: 160%, missing a -

Comment: You're right I am missing a negative! however the animation isn't running at all, so adding it didn't help.  I also tried adding 0%, but that didn't help either

Comment: My issue was that my animation name was in quotes, eg `"slideIn"`. Took the quotes out and it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the case for you, but I had mine inside a media query and IE seemed to ignore them, doesn't like the @ in an @ declaration.

Comment: I should have elaborated, but my solution was to move the updated keyframes outside of the media query and rename it instead of allowing it to override the original keyframe animation of the same name inside the media query.

Then in the media query, I called the renamed animation to overwrite the original and IE seemed happy with that.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of jQuery you're using, this solution works fine in IE11. I have replaced your IDs for Classes as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/1tcnz4j7/15/

```
<ul class="menulist">
        <li>
            <a  title=" Restaurants" href="/restaurants.php">Restaurants</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a title=" Calculator" href="/calculator.php">Nutrition Calculator</a>
        </li>

</ul>

<div class="menubutton">Button</div>

$(document).on('click', '.menubutton', function(){
    var object = $('.menulist');
    var openData = 'slidein';
    $(object).css('display','block').addClass(openData);
});
```

I would also put your DOM elements into variables. And you might also want to check if it has already slided too.

Comment: You're right it does work in jsfiddle. In fact I copied the code for the entire page (what I have above is just a snippet) and it worked.

I made sure I"m on the same version of jquery, so I don't know what the problem is.  Here's a link to the code in action: http://www.fastfoodnutrition.org/test/

Comment: Which link will slide out in this one? In IE7-9 animations won't work, so you need to include http://modernizr.com/ somewhere in your <head>.

Comment: If you shrink the width of your browser window to be mobile sized, you'll see the "hamburger" menu icon appears in the top header. When you click on that, the main navigation (restaurants, nutrition calculator, etc) should slide in from the right.

Since this is only for mobile I'm not too concerned with IE7-9.

Thanks for the help!